# Set the default version in modulefiles

Tags: environment-modules, modulefile

Given a directory containing modulefiles for several versions, how does one set a default so that the user can type `module load random_tool` without having to specify the version number?

```sh
% ls random_tool
1.2 2.3 3.0
```

Answer (score 5):

Given a directory of modulefiles:

```
% cd random_tool
% ls 
1.2 2.3 3.0
```

You can set one of them to be the default by creating a `.version` file. For example let's say we want 2.3 to be the default.  We create the following `.version` file.

```
#%Module

set ModulesVersion 2.3
```

Now when a person loads `random_tool` they will get version 2.3.

```sh
% module load random_tool
% random_tool --version
2.3
%
```